# use of '{% load staticfiles %}' in css import

Tags: django

Do I have to write `{% load staticfiles %}` when importing CSS files in my Django templates using `{{ STATIC_URL }}` template tag

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}abc/xyz/form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all you need is `'django.template.context_processors.static'` included in the `context_processors` section of the `TEMPLATES`' `OPTIONS` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: And what in case of                                                                               `<script src="{% static 'common/js/jquery.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: In that case, `{% load static %}` or `{% load staticfiles %}` is necessary - nb. in  Django 1.10 `{% load staticfiles %}` exists for backward compatibility and will probably be deprecated in 2.0.